# How do you check if a object in a class is initialized?

Tags: c#

I have a a `mainclass` with various subclasses.

```
 public class Mainclass
    {
    public List<main> mainset { get; set; }
 // do sth to load and save model info
    }
    public class main
{
    public personalinfo info { get; set; }
    public addressinfo currentaddr { get; set; }
    public addressinfo[] otheraddr { get; set; }
    public telephone currenttel { get; set; }
    public telephone[] othertel { get; set; }
 }
public class addressinfo
{
    public string Addressline1 { get; set; } 
    public string Addressline2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; 
}
public class telephone
{
    public int tel { get; set; }
}
```

How do I check if the children are initialized? I have tried the following but I am getting Null exception even when I try to check for !Null.

```
if (main.currentaddr != null)
{
addressinfo add = new addressinfo();
//do sth
}
```

Comment: I think your `main` object is null.

Comment: If that's failing, it's because `main` itself is null. Additionally, you should really follow .NET naming conventions - it'll make your code a lot easier for everyone else to understand.

Comment: Oh hell, I beat Jon Skeet. Sorry, but I'm quite excited about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this is failing is because the `main` variable is null. So you should check that before attempting to call `currentaddr` on it. It's pretty unclear from the source code you have shown where is this variable coming from and how you are initializing it but you could add the following test:

```
if (main != null && main.currentaddr != null)
{
    addressinfo add = new addressinfo();
    //do sth 
}
```

Comment: You were right the `main` class was null as it is pulled up from a XML file but in my XML i had the element name wrong so `main` wasnt loaded.